# Could not parse as expression when trying to populate check boxes in thymeleaf form

Tags: html, spring-boot, checkbox, thymeleaf

I am trying to populate values in an thymeleaf html form from model object returned from spring boot and below is the code. instance is the main object which contains an array ,channel, containing values like [web, corp, mobile]

```
<div th:object = "${instance}">

<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"  >Applicable on</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input class="input-style" type="checkbox" value="web" id="channel1" name="channel" th:checked="${(instance.channel.contains("web")
            )}">
            web
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input class="input-style" type="checkbox" value="corp" id="channel2" name="channel" th:checked="${(instance.channel.contains("corp")
                )}">
                corp
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input class="input-style" type="checkbox" value="mobile" id="channel3" name="channel" th:checked="${(instance.channel.contains("mobile")
                )}">
                mobile
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When running the application, I get the below error

```
Cannot render error page for request [/5cdaabf9d7d4ae55db7ad1ae] and exception [Could not parse as expression: "${(instance.channel.contains(" (template: "editFilter" - line 199, col 94)] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code
```

Can someone help me with how to fix and populate check boxes in the form from array ?

Comment: `${(instance.channel.contains('mobile'))}` instead of `${(instance.channel.contains("mobile"))}`

Comment: @Metroids : Not working

Comment: Well, the error message should have changed.  Your attribute was invalid because you had double quotes in it.  So what's wrong now?

Comment: @Metroids : Same error Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(instance.channel.contains('web')
         )" (template: "editFilter" - line 199, col 94)] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.

Comment: @Metroids : same error. any suggestions ?